# what the meaning of "Discovered Package: ...."

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new at laravel, and I'm trying to update composer, it is updated but I found some message but I can't understand it!!
it is about "Discovered Package"

**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\FinalPoject>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Updating fideloper/proxy (4.0.0 => 4.1.0): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: [32marrilot/laravel-widgets[39m
Discovered Package: [32mbeyondcode/laravel-dump-server[39m
Discovered Package: [32mfideloper/proxy[39m
Discovered Package: [32mintervention/image[39m
Discovered Package: [32mlarapack/voyager-hooks[39m
Discovered Package: [32mlaravel/nexmo-notification-channel[39m
Discovered Package: [32mlaravel/slack-notification-channel[39m
Discovered Package: [32mlaravel/tinker[39m
Discovered Package: [32mnesbot/carbon[39m
Discovered Package: [32mnunomaduro/collision[39m
Discovered Package: [32mtcg/voyager[39m
[32mPackage manifest generated successfully.[39m
```

**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look into your composer.json file you might find following script:

```
"scripts": {
        ...
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    }
```

This command `php artisan package:discover` helps laravel to discover any new supported libraries or packages when running `composer update`

If you do not want to do so, just remove that script from composer.json file. However, I don't see why would you wanna do that.

Additional info, on production server,never run `composer update`, always run `composer install` that way it will take the packages from `composer.lock` file and only install those libraries and you avoid the risk of updating some library and run into compatibility issues.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Your answer is almost correct, running composer install still runs `php artisan package:discover`. You would just simply have to remove the command from the composer.json.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to stop it,
but I asked about it because I didn't add these packages.
Do I have to add it?

Comment: I would recommend that because these are the packages which are possible dependencies of the packages you are already using and removing those might make you run into some issues. Take it like this, you installed a library A, a new version of lib A came which uses a dependency package B, so now when you run `composer update`, it will also discover and install package B which you directly had nothing to do with but uninstalling B might make lib A not work properly..makes sense?

Comment: it breaks Pusher build in a docker `Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
In Pusher.php line 63:
                                                                               
  Pusher\Pusher::__construct(): Argument #1 ($auth_key) must be of type strin  
  g, null given, called in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broad  
  casting/BroadcastManager.php on line 235  `