# Unable to find ClientObserver following Laravel update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan, laravel-6

After updating my project from Laravel v5.7.11 to v6.0.3, I received the following error at the end of the `composer update`:

```
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDum
@php artisan package:discover

   InvalidArgumentException  : Unable to find observer: App\Observer\ClientObserver

  at /usr/local/var/www/system-panel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.php:86
    82|         if (class_exists($class)) {
    83|             return $class;
    84|         }
    85| 
  > 86|         throw new InvalidArgumentException('Unable to find observer: '.$class);
    87|     }
    88| 
    89|     /**
    90|      * Get the observable event names.

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveObserverClassName("App\Observer\ClientObserver")
      /usr/local/var/www/system-panel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.php:56

  2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::registerObserver("App\Observer\ClientObserver")
      /usr/local/var/www/system-panel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.php:42
```

The ClientObserver class is sitting in the Observers directory within the App directory. `App/Observers/ClientObserver`

The client observer is defined as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Passport\Client;
use Uuid;

class ClientObserver
{
     ....
}
```

I expected the function to run as previously, without issue. Nothing has been changed besides the updating of the packages.

The `php artisan` also no longer works, it returns the same error.

Has anyone had this issue, and if so what was the fix?

Comment: Did you update the composer ?

Comment: @Casper Yeah, I updated to v1.9.0. Error still persists

Comment: Read those, https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/unable-to-find-observer-after-update-to-58, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648518/what-the-meaning-of-discovered-package

Comment: First one I read over earlier and it's not quite related. However, I followed the instructions and it did not resolve my issue. I tested the suggestions of the second link and it also did not fix the problem

Comment: Somehow you managed to figured it out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was in my `AppServiceProvider.php`. The use statements were referencing singular `App\Observer` rather than the expected directory name `App\Observers` where the ClientObserver is located.

Once updated the command ran without error.